# create a first column to two files

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I have these two files that contain the same thing, that is to say:

```
$ cat fileA.txt fileB.txt
1 2 3 
4 5 6 
7 8 9
```

Filter the files fileA.txt and fileB.txt in such a way that two new files are created with a new first column with the letter A and B in each column respectively. For example:

```
$ cat fileAa.txt
A 1 2 3
A 4 5 6
A 7 8 9
```

thought in `awk '{print "A",$0}' fileA.txt` , but I don't really know how to make it simultaneous for two files, I think a *for* would be enough

Comment: Welcome. Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: @steeldriver no! i'm just studying bash and awk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you certainly *could* use a shell loop, Awk is perfectly capable of processing multiple files directly ex. given

```
$ head file{A,B}.txt
==> fileA.txt <==
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9

==> fileB.txt <==
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

then

```
$ awk '{print v, $0 > "file" v "a.txt"}' v=A fileA.txt v=B fileB.txt
```

produces

```
$ head file{A,B}a.txt
==> fileAa.txt <==
A 1 2 3
A 4 5 6
A 7 8 9

==> fileBa.txt <==
B 1 2 3
B 4 5 6
B 7 8 9
```